# Откуда берутся неправильные ссылки при переносе сайта на WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Проблема в следующем. При переносе сайта с локалки на хостинг откуда-то берутся ссылки на локальный сайт. Было site.loc - стало site.ru. При переносе в базе данных изменила все ссылки, там совпадений по site.loc нет. На всякий случай проверила поиском по всему сайту, может быть в шаблонах где-то осталось, но тоже нет.

При переносе была проблема, что плагин WP Mega Menu оставил в меню ссылки на site.loc, но я заново сформировала меню, и вроде бы все ссылки стали правильными. Но, если смотреть через screaming frog, где-то остались эти пути, которые ведут на локальный сайт.

Предвижу, что будут комменты, что переносить вручную сайт не православно, но что уж теперь поделать, как можно в данной ситуации убить эти неправильные ссылки?

Comment: Всё написано давно на StackOverflow: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress

Comment: @KAGGDesign  вопрос не по теме этого вопроса ! Не знаешь как сделать такой же outline как в firefox , вот к примеру это dotted но он очень тонкий ...меньше 1px

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Чего проще-то? http://take.ms/Bx7ud

Comment: @KAGGDesign  охренеть - не знал ..спс